# Alternative to navigator.geolocation api

Tags: javascript

My employer is looking to implement a "near me" feature in our SaaS mapping application. We were planning to implement the navigator.geolocation API, but since our clients point their custom domains to our solution, we are unable to serve it consistently. Our solution doesn't support HTTPS yet, and as of v50, Chrome blocks geolocation over insecure origins.

Are there any alternative approaches?

Answer (score 0):

The closest you'll get is using IP address mapping, but that's far from precise and reliable. I'm sure you already thought of that, though.

The only other thing that comes to mind is using one of the wrappers. Not sure if you're building a mobile or desktop app, but is wrapping in Cordova or Electron an option?

Comment: Cordova and Electron are both good suggestions, but unfortunately, they aren't viable in our situation.  Thanks for the contribution though.